# Semidirect product with isomorphic copies of complements

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

The definition of semidirect group on Rotman's Introduction to the theory of groups is the following:

A group $G$ is a semidirect product of $K$ by $Q$, denoted by $G=K \rtimes Q$, if $K \lhd G$ and $K$ has a complement $Q_1 \cong Q$.

The definition of complement is this one:

If $K \leq G$, $Q \leq G$ is a complement of $K$ if their intersection is trivial and $KQ = G$.

There are a few things I do not quite understand here.

- I know that, if $K$ has complements, they're all isomorphic to each other; now, if a subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to a complement of $K$, will it also be a complement for it? In other words, if $KQ = G$ and $Q_1 \cong Q$, is it also $KQ_1 = G$?
- $Q_1$ in the definition of semidirect product is a subgroup of $G$, because it's a complement for $K$ and all complements are, by definition, subgroups of $G$. However, all we know about $Q$ is that it's isomorphic to $Q_1$; it may well be not even a subset of $G$, which means $G = K \rtimes Q$ can't be a strict set-theoretical equivalence. Why bother with $Q$? Why not just $G = K \rtimes Q_1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first question, no. It is even possible for a subgroup to have a complement isomorphic to itself (consider any group of the form $G\times G$). The last part is related to the fact that often when we write $K\rtimes Q$ mean mean the external semidirect product, which is constructed similarly to the direct product and does not need $Q$ to be (very much at least) related to $K$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, could you elaborate a bit on your answer to the first question? I am not sure I understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: In the group $G\times G$ you have a subgroup consisting of all elements of the form $(g,1)$ which is isomorphic to $G$ and has a complement consisting of elements of the form $(1,g)$ which is also isomorphic to $G$. So the first mentioned subgroup is isomorphic to its complement but it is clearly not a complement for itself.